# Notification when a application is downloaded in ios

Tags: ios, ios5, iphone-3gs

I am developing a application where i need to get the timestamp of a application when that application is downloaded. I searched many sites but didn't get any useful information so if anybody having any idea about it please share it. Any links related to the topic is also appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a normal iPhone. The best you could manage is the timestamp that the application is first run (this is usually pretty soon after downloading!)

(You *might* be able to do it in a jailbroken one).